# Trying to update a document with 7 fields (Flutter firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  Future _saveCourse(
      String coursename,
      String cid,
      String coursecredit,
      String coursetutor,
      String coursetutoremail,
      String coursetype,
      String coursemajor) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').doc(cid).update({
      'coursename': coursename,
      'coursecredit': coursecredit,
      'coursetutor': coursetutor,
      'coursetutoremail': coursetutoremail,
      'coursetype': coursetype,
      'coursemajor': coursemajor,
    });
  }
```

I am getting this error:

> E/flutter (16143): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that no document with the ID of your `cid` variable exists, and calling `update` is only valid on an existing document.